# Regex to match may keys taht contain ($)

Tags: java, regex

Method to filter Map where regex `($)` is matched :

```
public Map getVariables(Map<String , String> nvp){

        Map map = nvp.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().matches("(($.*?))"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        return map;

    }
```

Setup a map that contains key/value "($test)", "test value" :

```
private Map<String , String> nvp = new HashMap<String , String>();
public void setup(){
    nvp.put("($test)", "test value");
}
```

Add a method to test that "($test)" is contained in the Map returned :

```
public void testGetVariables(){

    OpDocVariableInsert o = new OpDocVariableInsert();
    System.out.println(o.getVariables(nvp).size());
}
```

But 0 results are returned. I think my regex is incorrect ?

Comment: `$` has a special meaning in regex, you should escape it: `\\$`. Also note that you should escape the `(` and `)` if you didn't mean to capture the match.

Comment: Note `\\(\\$[^)]++\\)` would be a more efficient pattern than using a lazy `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` and `()` have special meanings in regex and should be escaped to match their original characters :

```
\\(\\$.*?\\)
```

Comment: Or using the fancy `Pattern.quote`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun my first thought too - wouldn't work all-at-once because of the `.*?`.  Using two `Pattern.quote` and concatting seems a little ugly...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Missed that.. sure, in this case quoting is better.